# Toast appearing at inappropriate time

Tags: java, android-studio

I have created if else statement in which if the user is registered, toast will display "User already registered", otherwise it will register the user and another toast will display "User registered successfully". But when i hit register button, both the toasts appear instead of just "user registered successfully". Tell me how the first toast should not appear with it. Below is my code.

```
if (dataSnapshot.child(username2et.getText().toString()).exists()) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(RegisterScreen.this, "Username already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    mDialog.dismiss();
    User user = new User(emailet.getText().toString(), password2et.getText().toString(), phonenoet.getText().toString(), carplatenoet.getText().toString());
    table_user.child(username2et.getText().toString()).setValue(user);
    Toast.makeText(RegisterScreen.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: There is not enough here to figure out what is going on. You need to provide more information. I am not sure what dataSnapshot is, how it is assigned, and what is assigned in it.

Comment: Mhm. My initial guess is that this piece of code is actually executed twice for each button press. But that's just that: a guess. As @JoshuaBlevins notes, more information is required.

Comment: I was thinking this or that some logic is incorrect.